# Ultimate Vault Hunter mode pack 2 not working

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, borderlands-2

I purchased Borderlands 2: Game of the Year Edition on PlayStation 3, and I have downloaded and installed all the included DLC's. Everything works fine.

When I reached level  61, I purchased and installed the Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode Pack 2 DLC. However, I still can not level past level 61, and when I attempt to enter the District Peak challenge, I am told that I do not have the Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode Pack 2 DLC.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you confirm you have the first vault hunter pack? I remembered it not being included with GOTY edition. My local retailer does specifically not list it as included, but **does** state that it includes "First level cap increase". However, My research seems to confirm that vault hunter pack 1 increases the level cap, vault hunter pack 2 unlocks the digistruct challenges. I don't have my old saves to check, personally

Answer (score 1):

Try re-downloading the DLC, I have  never had any issues with the Borderlands 2 DLC that could not be solved that way.

Comment: yea i already re-downloaded it several times, but it just never "activates"

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get gearbox support @ https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/home

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Possible things what to do (in this order preferably):

- Wait a while; it could be just delayed
- Re-download the DLC and wait
- Steam: If you didn't already, Validate game files (right click Borderlands 2, go to Local Data Tab and 'Clock Check game files' or something simmilar)
- Reinstall the game
- Contact a devleloper / administrator

I checked online, all these methods helped at least once.